# MongoDB Cannot apply $addToSet to non-array in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I want to make an array of users, who upvoted post, to allow them upvote only once per post. I want to add users who upvoted to the array, to deny them multiple clicks. But when I try $addToSet to array, I get MongoDB cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array.

```
'click a.yes': function(event) {
        if (Meteor.user()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var postId = Session.get('selected_post');
            Posts.update(postId, {$addToSet: {users: Meteor.user()}});
            Posts.update(postId, {$inc: {'score' : 1}});
```

Here is the structure of the post, with users array,

```
Template.postSubmit.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var post = {
      yak: $(e.target).find('[name=yak]').val(),
      submitted: new Date(),
      score: 0,
      users: ({})
    };

    post._id = Posts.insert(post);
    Router.go('postsList', post);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have looked at the document you created. That is not how you notate an empty array for serializing in JSON notation. You should have done:

```
var post = {
  yak: $(e.target).find('[name=yak]').val(),
  submitted: new Date(),
  score: 0,
  users: []
};
```

Because right now, your "users" field looks like this:

```
"users" : {  }
```

Or possibly better yet don't even initialize the field at all and [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) will just take care of it for you and create the element when there is something new to add.

Schema-less data-stores like MongoDB usually don't require you to go an pre-initialize things like this.